# Change order of columns in pandas dataframes in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a number of `pandas.Dataframe` objects and want to reorder the columns of all of them in a `for` loop, but it's not working. What I have is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 5))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 5))

dfs = [ df1, df2 ]
```

Now, changing the name of the columns works:

```
for df in dfs:
    df.columns = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ]

df1.head()
```

prints (columns with letters instead of numbers):

```
          a         b         c         d         e
0  0.276383  0.655995  0.512101  0.793673  0.165763
1  0.841603  0.831268  0.776274  0.670846  0.847065
2  0.626632  0.448145  0.184613  0.763160  0.337947
3  0.502062  0.881765  0.154048  0.908834  0.669257
4  0.254717  0.538606  0.677790  0.088452  0.014447
```

However, changing the order of the columns is not working in the same way. The following loop:

```
for df in dfs:
    df = df[ [ 'e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a' ] ]
```

leaves the dataframes unchanged.

If I do it for each dataframe, outside the for loop, it works, though:

```
df1 = df1[ [ 'e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a' ] ]
df1.head()
```

prints the following:

```
          e         d         c         b         a
0  0.165763  0.793673  0.512101  0.655995  0.276383
1  0.847065  0.670846  0.776274  0.831268  0.841603
2  0.337947  0.763160  0.184613  0.448145  0.626632
3  0.669257  0.908834  0.154048  0.881765  0.502062
4  0.014447  0.088452  0.677790  0.538606  0.254717
```

---

Why can't I loop over the dataframes to change the column order?

How can I loop over the dataframes in the list to change the column order?

---

Working with python 3.5.3, pandas 0.23.3

Comment: I find it really interesting. So basically you want to iterate over `dfs` list, and then see the changes done in the loop when calling `df1`, not `dfs[0]`, am I right? I am very curious, why modifying in the first loop (i.e. changing the columns' names) works this way, but rearranging columns doesn't.

Comment: @pmarcol Yeah, want to keep using `df1` for other things later in the code.

Comment: See my answer then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've spent a while on it, it actually gave me a nice puzzle.
It works this way, because in your first loop you *modify* the existing objects, but in the second loop you actually create *new* objects and *overwrite* the old ones; by that the list `dfs` loses its references to `df1` and `df2`. If you want the code to work in the way that after second loop you'd like to see the changes applied to `df1` and `df2`, you can only use methods, that operate on the original dataframe and do not require overwriting.
I'm not convinced that my way is the optimal one, but that's what I mean:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 5))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 5))

dfs = [ df1, df2 ]

for df in dfs:
    df.columns = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ]

for df in dfs:
    for c in ['e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']:
        df.insert(df.shape[1],c+'_new',df[c])
    #df.drop(['e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a'], axis=1)
    for c in [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ]:
        del df[c]
    df.columns = ['e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']
```

Then calling `df1` prints:

```
           e           d           c           b           a
0   0.550885    0.879557    0.202626    0.218867    0.266057
1   0.344012    0.767083    0.139642    0.685141    0.559385
2   0.271689    0.247322    0.749676    0.903162    0.680389
3   0.643675    0.317681    0.217223    0.776192    0.665542
4   0.480441    0.981850    0.558303    0.780569    0.484447
```

Comment: Your explanation is good, about modify and overwrite objects... It'd be good to find a nicer way to rearrange the columns, though...

Comment: Yes, I would also like to see less 'hackery' way, but I couldn't find a method that would not require overwriting the original object.

Comment: If you stumble upon some `reindex` or similar, rememeber to come back and edit your answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use `enumerate` and remember to assign back into your `list`:

```
for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
    dfs[i] = df[['e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to change the column order in the original dataframes either (`df1`, `df2`).

Comment: No, it wont change the original object `inplace`. Would likely need the inverse of your `dfs` assignment operation - `df1, df2 = dfs` after the `for` loop

Comment: Indeed, that would do the trick. @ChrisA Would you mind adding that to your answer? I think it's worth it.