# Pandas dataframe, change column order using reindex does give expected result in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have two dataframes that look the same and for both of them I want to add an additional column and then reorder the columns. Here is a sample of what I tried to accomplish this:

```
data=[[1,2],[3,4]]
cols=['col1','col2']

df1=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=cols)
df2=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=cols)

for df in [df1,df2]:
    df.loc[:,'col3']=[5,6]
    df=df.reindex(['col3','col2','col1'],axis=1)

print(df1)

      col1  col2  col3
    0     1     2     5
    1     3     4     6

print(df2)

      col1  col2  col3
    0     1     2     5
    1     3     4     6
```

The third column was added as expected but the columns are still in the original order. I expected them to be col3, col2, col1. When I tried this later on the reindex worked as expected:

```
df1=df1.reindex(['col3','col2','col1'],axis=1)
```

I'm sure there is an explanation to why the column gets added but the reindex is ignored in my first attempt, but I have not been able to find one. Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because df in your for loop is a local variable. When you do `df.loc[:,'col3']=[5,6]`, you do a *modification* to the thing `df` references, which therefore affects `df1`. However, doing
`df.reindex(['col3','col2','col1'],axis=1)` does not modify the original DataFrame but creates a new copy of it, which is then assigned to the local variable `df` inside the for loop. However, `df1` and `df2` remain unchanged. To see this, you can try printing `df` at the end of the for loop. It should print the desired value you want for `df2` (with the reindexing)

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. Just out of curiosity, what would be a good way to rewrite this so the  original dataframes are updated? This works, but is probably not the most efficient way to do it: `def change(df):
    df.loc[:,'col3']=[5,6]
    df=df.reindex(['col3','col2','col1'],axis=1,copy=False)
    return df

df1=change(df1)
df2=change(df2)`

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the way assignments work in Python. When you called `df.loc[:,'col3']=[5,6]`, Python (correctly) interpreted this as "change `loc[:,'col3']` of the object called `df` to `[5,6]`". On the other hand, when you called `df = df.reindex(['col3', 'col2', 'col1'], axis=1)`, you were *expecting* this to be interpreted as "replace the object called `df` with the reindexed dataframe". What it *actually* did was redefine the label `df` so that it refers to the reindexed dataframe (without changing the object that `df` used to refer to).

Comment: I tried this as well but this does not work either as the reindex will not change the original dataframes (df1 and df2).

Comment: You're right, my suggestion doesn't work, so I've removed it. Apparently, [it's impossible to reindex a dataframe in place](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56462088/2476977). So, there is no way to implement this change such that the original variables are updated; you'll have to overwrite them.